# Generic Type Variable with type narrowing

Tags: typescript

Is this behaviour a bug in Typescript 2.0.3? How could i improve the function definition?

```
function cleanString<T>(path: T): T {
    if (path === null || path === undefined || typeof path !== 'string') {
        return path;
    }
    return path.replace(/\\+/g, '/');   // <- path is never here
}
```

**Expected behavior:**
Should compile with no issue

**Actual behavior:** 
`path` is `never` in the last line.

```
function cleanString(path: any)
```

would work, but looses the (input type == output type) information.

`(<any>path)` works, but is not elegant.

Based on Nitzan Tomer ideas i found:

```
function cleanString<T>(path: T): T;
function cleanString(path) {
    if (typeof path === 'string') {
        return path.replace(/\\+/g, '/').replace(/\/+/g, '/').replace(/^\/+/g, '');
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: What is `T`? What can it be other than string?

Comment: [T is replaced](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) with a type with a call like `cleanString<number>(variab);` or are autogenerated by the varible you put into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do some casting:

```
function cleanString<T>(path: T): T {
    if (path === null || path === undefined || typeof path !== 'string') {
        return path;
    }

    return (path as string).replace(/\\+/g, '/') as any;
}

let num = cleanString(3); // type of num is number
let bool = cleanString(true); // type of bool is boolean
let str = cleanString("string"); // type of str is string
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20cleanString%3CT%3E(path%3A%20T)%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(path%20%3D%3D%3D%20null%20%7C%7C%20path%20%3D%3D%3D%20undefined%20%7C%7C%20typeof%20path%20!%3D%3D%20'string')%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20path%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(path%20as%20string).replace(%2F%5C%5C%2B%2Fg%2C%20'%2F')%20as%20any%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20num%20%3D%20cleanString(3)%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20num%20is%20number%0Alet%20bool%20%3D%20cleanString(true)%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20bool%20is%20boolean%0Alet%20str%20%3D%20cleanString(%22string%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20str%20is%20string))

---

#### Edit

If you don't like the use of `any`, and if `T` can be a limited set of types, then you can do:

```
function clean(path: string): string;
function clean(path: boolean): boolean;
function clean(path: number): number;
function clean(path) {
    if (typeof path === "string") {
        return path.replace(/\\+/g, '/');
    }

    return path;
}

let num = clean(3); // type of num is number
let bool = clean(true); // type of bool is boolean
let str = clean("string"); // type of str is string
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20clean(path%3A%20string)%3A%20string%3B%0Afunction%20clean(path%3A%20boolean)%3A%20boolean%3B%0Afunction%20clean(path%3A%20number)%3A%20number%3B%0Afunction%20clean(path)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20path%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20path.replace(%2F%5C%5C%2B%2Fg%2C%20'%2F')%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20path%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20num%20%3D%20clean(3)%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20num%20is%20number%0Alet%20bool%20%3D%20clean(true)%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20bool%20is%20boolean%0Alet%20str%20%3D%20clean(%22string%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20of%20str%20is%20string))

Comment: Ok, that works. But this is nearly equivalent to my <any> solution.

Comment: Right, I missed the last sentence of your question with the `(<any>path)`. Check my revised answer, I added another solution which is more elegant but will work only if `T` is limited to a number of known types.